# What's the driving force of this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

The question is to find the major product in this reaction-

> [image]

And this is the answer given-
[image]

The first step seems to be a kind of intramolecular S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction. But how can it occur on this carbon which has a lot of steric hindrance. What is the driving force of this reaction? I have never seen such a reaction that occurs solely on giving heat except, of course, dehydration reactions.

Edit- I am asking about the driving force of the first step.

Comment: *"What is the driving force of this reaction?"* Are you asking for the driving force of the first step, or the entire reaction? *"under what topic will it be?"* Well, that's not for me to decide, that's for your teacher or your textbook to decide. *"I have never seen such a reaction that occurs solely on giving heat"* There are lots more out there which I'm sure you'll see in due course. Also, you can't "give heat" to a reaction. You just heat it, or it "occurs upon heating".

Comment: Also, I've searched, and I can't find any reports of this reaction in the literature. As far as I can tell, nobody has even made the starting material before. Where is this question from? Is it a reaction that you or somebody else has done?

Comment: @Orthocresol It would most likely be a question in a book. [I assume that they were asking OP to use anchimeric effect here]. Also, the curly arrow given here seems to wrong. It should have attacked the carbon connecting the Br and not the adjacent C-C bond

Comment: @Safdar Indeed,IIRC the source for this is Himanshu Pandey.

Comment: I don't have access to literature sources as of now,and so I can't comment on whether this reaction has actually been done. But what I can say on a purely theoretical basis is that being an intramolecular reaction increases the chances of collisions as compared to an intermolecular case of trying an SN2 with a tertiary halide. Also, not a lot of nuclear rearrangement is taking place in the first step,so that may contribute to the speed of the reaction as per the principle of least motion. But yes, would the methylpyrrole break aromaticity to even do this this reaction is questionable as well

Comment: @YusufHasan You recall correctly.

Comment: @orthocresol I edited the question and removed the "under what topic" part.

Comment: Alright. Indoles are quite nucleophilic and like to do this sort of intramolecular attack on electrophiles, so the SN2 step doesn't strike me as being all that bad, also taking into account what @YusufHasan said (which is right). I don't know what would happen *after* that, though. I don't know why the reaction should go in the forward direction, or why the product should be favoured over the reactant (after all, there is a reverse pathway involving the same steps), or whether you could even have an alkyl migration in the intermediate cyclopropane (this is also a known pattern with indoles).

Comment: Now, the problem with reactions that have never been done before, is that you end up digging for an explanation for something that may not even be real. So I really don't want to come up with some explanation that sounds authoritative but has no meaning.

Comment: Looks like a (very hacky) SN-NGP (Nucleophilic substitution with Neighbouring Group Participation) question.